# How to access an entity within an entity in twig

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony5

In my controller, I return the entity so that my twig template can use it like so:

```
return $this->render('review/index.html.twig',[
     "list" => $applications
]);
```

`$applications` is a query that returns the object I'm looking for:

```
$applications = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(ApplicationQueue::class)->findBy(
      array("assignment_mod_user" => $this->getUser()->getId())
);
```

And within my twig, I use the dump function to see if it's retrieving what I'm looking for. This is what is returned:

[image]

As you can see, there are two entities associated to this entity. In twig when I tired to do this, it failed to retrieve the data within:

```
{% for application in list %}
     {{application.application.[whateverhere]}}
{% endfor %}
```

How do I access the entities within an entity in twig when the data is already being pushed? The current output returns the error of:

`Neither the property "application" nor one of the methods "application()", "getapplication()"/"isapplication()"/"hasapplication()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "App\Entity\ApplicationQueue".`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add an accessor to get the value of $application. This property is currently not accessible from outside the ApplicationQueue class.

```
class ApplicationQueue
{
    protected $application;

    public function getApplication(): CreatorApplication
    {
        return $this->application;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... so then what? How do you access that in twig? Do you need to call that function within twig, or pass it through the controller? A little more information could be helpful here.

Comment: Ok I understood, but might be worth to explain it. Each entity needs to have a function that retrieves the foreign entity, and within that foreign entity, there needs to be a function like `getUserName` to retrieve the data within twig. Then you can call that function within twig like so `application.application.user.getusername`

Answer (score 0):

You have tu put double curly braces around your variable, like that :

```
{{ application.application.name }}
```

Look at the twig doc :

```
{% for user in users %}
    <li>{{ user.username|e }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Apologies, but the curly brackets are actually there. Updated my question.

Comment: Can you please share you Entities ?